# "Phone" item using 10-15% of Battery Life

Tags: samsung-galaxy-nexus, battery-life

I've attempted to search for other questions answering this, but keyword ambiguity is working against me.

On my Galaxy Nexus, my battery drains rather quickly. Very frequently, when viewing the battery use details, the "Phone" item is the second-largest battery use after Screen. Items such as Cell Standby use much less. This happens even on days when I do not make any voice calls, so I'm not certain what this could be.

Is there something I can do to reduce this battery drain? What causes "Phone" to use this much battery?

edit: Here's a screenshot demonstrating what I'm talking about. I don't believe I made or received any calls on this day.

[image: screen shot]

Comment: Could you add/link a screenshot of the corresponding "battery usage" screen? That may make things a bit clearer.

Answer (score 0):

Try booting into safe mode. It should set things right up. You could determine the problem much easier there. That will turn off all 3rd party services, leaving plain android behind.

To goto Safe Mode,
Press the Power button on your device.
Touch & hold the Power off option in the dialog box.
Touch OK in the following dialog to start safe mode.